# Windows MediaPack not correctly installed

Tags: windows, windows-media-player, windows-10-v1511

I was trying to install the Windows Media Pack for my Windows 10 Pro N Edition, which was necessary after updating to Version 1511.

The problem is now, that the MediaPack was successfully installed, but there are no new MediaFeatures listed in "Turn Windows features on or off", which means that i dont have access to the Media Player, nor cant i uninstall the Media Pack to try again. Windows does not allow me to reinstall the MediaPack as shown in the picture below.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Thx in advance.

[image]
[image]

**Uninstalling**

Uninstalling KB3010081 via cmd gives me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Before the Update the Media Pack was successfully installed and working. Windows does not allow me to uninstall the KB. Can i force Windows to do so or do i have to try the rollback? One more thing: The Kb ist not listed in the "Uninstall an update" Section

Comment: I did the roll back and its working in the older version. I guess now update for me then.

Comment: the Media Pack can't be uninstall officially. Do you want to apply a hack?

Comment: What kind of hack? :D

Comment: editing a windows file. Run notepad.exe as admin, go to **C:\Windows\servicing\Packages**, find the Package_for_KB3010081 MUM (not the other MUMs with the KB number) and remove the entry **permanence="permanent"** but make sure you don't remove the **>**. now try to uninstall the update

Comment: @Marty post a list of all KB3010081 MUm files in the folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a newer version of `Media Feature Pack` — [KB3133719](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53356). It should fix the issues with your current installation.

Comment: Exact same problem as the op. The version you shared when installed returns with "This update is not applicable to your computer"

Comment: @user986363 You should use the version applicable to your Windows build – [Media Feature Pack list for Windows N editions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3145500/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions)

Answer (score 0):

Installing via "Add or Remove programs" -> Optional Features solved the similar problem. 
[image]

https://borncity.com/win/2019/11/14/media-feature-pack-windows-10-n-1909/