# Windows 10 N x64 1703 Media Feature Pack installed blocked by 1607 Feature Pack

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-media-player

I updated my Windows 10 x64 N machine to 1703. As usual, I tracked down the appropriate media feature pack to install.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016817/media-feature-pack-for-n-edition-of-windows-10-version-1703-april-2017

It installed and then asked me to reboot. I did so, but no media features appeared. I ran the above installer again, and it gave me this message:

[image: Feature Pack for Windows (KB3133719) is already installed on this computer.]

At first I thought it was telling me it was already installed. But upon closer inspection, KB3133719 is *not* the update I installed -- it's the feature pack for the previous version of Windows 10, 1607.

I'm kind of stuck here. There doesn't seem to be a way of uninstalling feature packs, short of reinstalling the OS (which I don't have time to do atm), but I can't get the feature pack installed (for those that don't know, this means that videos on the internet won't play, and all sorts of games and apps will work incorrectly or not at all -- it's not just windows media player).

Comment: Submit the results of winver for us

Comment: Based on this near duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1002336/windows-mediapack-not-correctly-installed the answer is to install the correct version of the media pack for your installation hence the reason I must see the results of winver.

Comment: My expert opinion would be to install: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack instead of what your attempting to install

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help Ramhound. https://i.imgur.com/p5tRJ4y.png is the output of winver: 1703. Regardless, I tried your advice, but as expected the 1709 feature pack doesn't install on 1703: https://i.imgur.com/lyJhAd1.png

Comment: remove the old update KB3133719 in control panel

Answer (score 0):

So I guess this isn't technically a solution to my precise problem, but updating Windows to 1709 and applying the feature pack for that version worked.